# How can I make a vector that checks if there are equal numbers in it?

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to create a vector that displays if there are equal numbers inside it if there are, an output will have to come out where it says that there are equal numbers if there are not the opposite,

EX: A(2,4,2,7) There are equal numbers

I'm trying any solution but can't figure out how to do it I'm at the beginning of the arrays.

Comment: You could copy the values into a [multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset), and check if any keys have a count larger than one.

Comment: Please post any of your solutions and the problems you have with it, including anz relevant debugging information you have gathered by stepping through the code with a debugger. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: What do you mean by "equal number"? Do you mean duplicate instances of the same value?  Or do you mean something like "the number 2 appears 2 times in the vector"?  Or something else?

Comment: I don't understand well can you show me how to code? thanks

Comment: @voltah - Can you try to explain what you mean by "equal numbers".  What are "equal numbers"?

Comment: @selbie for example A(2,2) there are same numbers "2 and 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to sort the vector first and then loop through the vector and check if current vector[i] == vector[i+1].

```
vector<int> yourVector{ 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
sort(yourVector.begin(), yourVector.end(), greater<int>());

int equalNum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < yourVector.size()-1; i++)
{
    if(yourVector[i] == yourVector[i+1])
    {
      equalNum++;
    }
}

if(equalNum > 0)
{
  std::cout << "There are: " << equalNum << "equal numbers" << std::endl;
}else{
  std::cout << "There no equal numbers" << std::endl;
}
```

This is just some code i just made up haven't tested it.

Comment: I don't understand well can you show me how to code? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use std::set, fill it from your vector and compare if the sizes are equal. If not you have duplicates.

```
std::vector<int> values{1,1,2,3,4,5,5}; 

std::set<int> tmp{values.begin(),values.end()}; 

bool duplicates = (values.size() != tmp.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to use a map instead:

```
unordered_map<int, int> numbers;

++numbers[2];
++numbers[4];
++numbers[2];
++numbers[7];
```

Now you can check how many of each number you have:

```
cout << "Number of twos: " << numbers[2] << '\n';
```